# Form adding /' to text file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form, that is writing to a text file. Then that text file is being displayed on a page. I THOUGHT that adding strip_tags would remove the issue, but it hasn't.

When I submit "I'm changing the content" i get "I/'m changing the content"

I can't remember the FREAKING name of what that "/" is, I could have sworn it was strip something. So obviously i'm having trouble searching for my solution as well.

here is the code, just in case it helps.

index.php

```
<body>

<?php include("whotitle.txt"); ?>
<br />
<?php include("whocontent.txt"); ?>
</body>
```

admin.php

```
<body>

<form name="web_form" id="web_form" method="post" action="process-whotitle.php">
        <p><label>Enter Title: </label><textarea type="text" name="WhoTitle"> <?php include("whotitle.txt"); ?> </textarea></p>
        <p><label>Enter Content: </label><textarea type="text" name="WhoContent"> <?php include("whocontent.txt"); ?> </textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>


</body>
```

process-whotitle.php

```
<?php
$whotitle = strip_tags( $_POST['WhoTitle'] );
$data = "$whotitle";
$fh = fopen("whotitle.txt", "w");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);

$whocontent = strip_tags( $_POST['WhoContent'] );
$data = "$whocontent";
$fh = fopen("whocontent.txt", "w");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
print "Info Submitted";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't remember the FREAKING name of what that "/" is, I could have
>   sworn it was strip something. So obviously i'm having trouble
>   searching for my solution as well.

[Stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) ??

Comment: yup... exactly what i needed

Answer (score 1):

stripslashes($variable) would remove the slashes

Answer (score 1):

An example how to use stripslashes:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That forward slash, im pretty sure you need to change it to "scape" slash in order to stripslashes to work:

stripslashes(str_replace("/", "\", $text));